# gwt-test-utils does not find my entry point class

Tags: java, gwt, junit, classpath, gwt-test-utils

I am trying to get gwt-test-utils to work. I set up the project in the following way:

```
src/main/java : all the java source code
src/test/java : the test source code
src/test/resources : resource files for the tests
```

I am building my project with gradle and eclipse. Gradle uses these directories correctly by default and I added all three of them as source directories to Eclipse.

I have successfully built and run the project and was able to execute some plain old JUnit tests as well as a `GWTTestCase`, so I think I set up the project and its dependencies correctly.

Now I wanted to use gwt-test-utils for some more advanced integration tests. To do so I did the following:

1. Add the gwt-test-utils and gwt-test-utils-csv to my dependencies

   ```
   gwtTestUtilsVersion = '0.45'
   testCompile group:'com.googlecode.gwt-test-utils', name:'gwt-test-utils', version:gwtTestUtilsVersion
   testCompile group:'com.googlecode.gwt-test-utils', name:'gwt-test-utils-csv', version:gwtTestUtilsVersion
   ```
2. Add a `gwt-test-utils.properties` file to the directory `src/test/resources/META-INF` with the following content:

   ```
   path/to/my/module = gwt-module
   ```
3. Added a class that extends GwtCsvTest to a package in the `src/test/java` directory. It is modeled after the second example in [HowToWriteCsvScenario](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-test-utils/wiki/HowToWriteCsvScenario) from the gwt-test-utils project wiki, replacing occurrence of their example classes with mine. It looks like this

   ```
   @CsvDirectory(value = "gwtTests")
   public class LoginLogoutTest extends GwtCsvTest
   {
       @Mock
       private MainServiceAsync mainService;

       private AppController appController = new AppController();

       @CsvMethod
       public void initApp()
       {
           appController.onModuleLoad();
       }

       @Before
       public void setup()
       {
           GwtFinder.registerNodeFinder("myApp", new NodeObjectFinder()
           {
               @Override
               public Object find(Node node)
               {
                   return csvRunner.getNodeValue(appController, node);
               }
           });

           GwtFinder.registerNodeFinder("loginView", new NodeObjectFinder()
           {
               @Override
               public Object find(Node node)
               {
                   return csvRunner.getNodeValue(appController.getRootPresenter().getCurrentlyActiveSubPresenters().iterator().next().getView(), node);
               }
           });

           addGwtCreateHandler(createRemoteServiceCreateHandler());
       }
   }
   ```
4. added a csv-file for configuring the test to `src/test/resources/gwtTests` with the following content

   start
   initApp
   assertExist;/loginView/emailTextBox

I tried executing it via the Eclipse's *Run As > JUnit Test* and indirectly via `gradle build` (which executes all the test cases, not just this one). Both lead to the same error:

```
ERROR GwtTreeLogger Unable to find type 'myPackage.client.AppController'
ERROR GwtTreeLogger Hint: Check that the type name 'myPackage.client.AppController' is really what you meant
ERROR GwtTreeLogger Hint: Check that your classpath includes all required source roots
```

The AppController class is the entry-point configured in the module I configured in `gwt-test-utils.properties`, which makes me think that configuration works correctly and the rest of the setup (dependencies and all) work as well.

In an earlier version I used the same file as a subclass of GWTTestCase and created an `AppController` instance in the same way. That worked, so I'm pretty sure the class path is setup correctly to include it as well. I also tried changing it back to the previous version just now and it still works.

I have no clue why the class is not found. Is there anything gwt-test-utils does differently which means I need to specifically set the class path for it? Otherwise it should just work, since both gradle and eclipse know about all the relevant source folders and dependencies.

Comment: This may be related to this [bug](https://github.com/gwt-test-utils/gwt-test-utils/issues/46). I had some luck by removing the entry-point from the gwt.xml file.